# Ardupilot Frame of Reference for X-Quad

Tags: autopilot, airframe

I was using pix hawk with Ardupilot : I want to know which frame of reference is used in pix hawk - Ardupilot - H configuration

when I am observing the valued in the logs the Acceleration Z is showing -10m/s^2

Answer (score 2):

The ArduPilot uses a NED (North-East-Down) axial orientation. This tells you  which direction gives a positive value.
If you see a negative Z value, that would indicate the Quad is taking off. When landing you should see a positive value.
Note that these 'directions' are based on the orientation of the PixHawk in relation to the Quad itself. So 'North' would be the front of the Quad.